# The model part of getting this info out of database in java

Tags: java, string, oop, javafx

note: This is just a rough sketch.

I have a program that will get questions out of the database with each questions options and answers(which are 4 options). Each options will be test against the answer and if any of the options selected equals to the answer, it will be added to an array which will be created and if unanswered, it will be added to another array.

This is the rough sketch of what I have.I do not say this code is correct, but a rough sketch. Meaning , I just wanna have the idea of how to create it or go about it.

```
String questionAnswerOption[][] = new String[][](){
String getAllQuestions = new String();
String getAllOptions = new String();
String getAllAnswers = new String();

String getAll[][] = new String getAll[getAllOptions.lenght][getAllAnswer.lenght];
int i,j;
String query = "SELECT id,question, options, answers FROM questions WHERE year = ? AND subject = ?";

//some database command intentionally omitted

    while(rs.next()){
        getAllQuestions = rs.getString("questions");
        getAllOptions =rs.getString("options");
        getAllAnswers = rs.getString("answers");

        for(i = 1; i<= getAllOptions.lenght; i++){
            for(j = 1; i<= getAllAnswers.lenght; i++){
                getAllOptions[i];
                getAllAnswers[i];

            }
        }
    }

} 

//for the presentation because I wanna use the MVP pattern

String correct[] = new String[];
String unattempted [] = new String[];
int i, j;

if(group.getSelectedToggle().getUserOption().toString().equals answers){
    correct[].add;
    i++;
}elseif(group.getSelectedToggle().getUserOption().toString().!equals answers){
    unattempted[].add;
    j++;
}
```

Comment: My first step would be to at least write valid, compiling Java code.

Comment: Actually, am trying to put it in an observableArrayList but don't know how to go about it in an observablearraylist. That is why I did a rough sketch. and again, am in a cafe. The minutes don't wait for me

Answer (score 0):

Just a rough sketch:

Retrieving a `Quiz` from the database:

```
interface QuizDao {

    Quiz getQuiz();
}
```

A quiz providing access to all questions. Questions answered correctly or not can be implemented as filters.

```
interface Quiz {

    Collection<Question> getAllQuestions();

    Collection<Question> getAnsweredQuestions();
}
```

A basic definition of a `Question` type.

```
interface Question {

  int getId();

  String getQuestion();

  Collection<String> getOptions();

  String getUserInput();

  void setUserInput(String value);

  boolean isUserInputCorrect();
}
```

Comment: can you enlighten me a little more